# transfer the lower triangular part of a matrix into a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

Let `a` be a matrix. The following code will transfer the lower triangular part of it into a vector if there is no 0-elements in the lower triangular part of it.

```
a(find(tril(a,-1)))
```

So, what shall I do if there is some 0-element in the lower triangular part of `a`? Thanks very much for your time and attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`mask`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) -

```
%// Mask of lower triangular elements
mask = tril(true(size(a)),-1)

%// Use mask to select lower triangular elements from input array
out = a(mask)
```

Alternatively, you can create the mask with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
mask = bsxfun(@gt,[1:size(a,1)]',1:size(a,2))
```

---

Sample run -

```
>> a
a =
     1     3     0     2     1
     0     1     1     3     1
     0     2     2     1     2
     3     0     1     3     2
     3     3     3     0     3
>> out
out =
     0
     0
     3
     3
     2
     0
     3
     1
     3
     0
```